# React scripts fails while i run concurrently with nodemon

Tags: reactjs

[image: Error]

When i run `npm start` the above error occurs.

**my script in package.json:**

```
"start": "concurrently \"nodemon server\" \"react-scripts start\"",
```

Any help will be great !

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO
Please never ever post images of text, add it as a formatted text block instead.
You can edit your question to provide the text instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the ways you can do is  (You can amend it accordingly) :

```
"server": "nodemon index.js",

"react": "react-scripts start"

"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server \" \"npm run react\" "
```

And then do `npm run dev`

You can read more about [concurrently here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Comment: What does it say ? Have you saved the above in your `packages.json`?

Comment: Yes I saved packages.json but same error appeared 
I did npm run dev
i am getting this error:
npm ERR! missing script: dev

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\shankar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-15T12_56_40_650Z-debug.log

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows platform and throws out an error about not knowing `concurrently "react-scripts start" "` and so on.